# What IIS version is required to host ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, deployment, asp.net-web-api

We're developing REST service using ASP.NET WebAPI.

Is there a required version of IIS for deploying the web application containing this service?

Comment: Did you try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+4+web+api+requiremenrs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=mvc+4+web+api+requirements&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt... first thing i did

Comment: I am not sure you won't bump into issues on 7.0 and I would recommend at least 7.5. I wonder what's the background of the question. Are you trying to target lowest possible version?

Comment: @WiktorZychla... Thanks for the reply Wiktor. In essence, yes. We need to know in order to inform the client on what the requirements would be for the service to work properly.